# SQL filtering with COALESCE or window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following simplified data:

```
PK    FK   Type
----------------
1     11    A
2     11    B
3     12    B
4     13    C
5     13    D
6     14    D
```

And I want a result set of:

```
PK    FK   Type
---------------
1     11    A
3     12    B
4     13    C
6     14    D
```

So if a given FK value has a Type A, don't give me any rows with B, C, or D.  Or if the value has a Type B, then filter out C and D, etc.  This feels like I need to apply a window function or coalesce, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: TSQL as in Sybase, or SQL Server?

Comment: So you are not clear, do you mean that if it has a value W, then only filter out X, Y and Z? Does that mean allow in A-V ?? But if any of those lower values existed, wouldn't that also imply that you filter out everything above that lower value ?? That would be equivilent to get everything with value equal to lowest letter in alphabet that exists and nothing else...

Comment: I'm using SQL server.  In my mind the values have priorities, so if there is an A, then return just that, otherwise if there is a B, return just that, etc.  Only one row would be returned for each FK value, that row with the highest priority Type value.

Comment: Your example data has the PKs and Types in the same order at all times, so there are a lot of answers that are doing things like sorting or ranking by the primary key and then returning the lowest primary key record. Make your sample data more complex, otherwise people will not notice the fact that you want to know the lowest `Type` -- and you might not notice if your code isn't working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM (SELECT s.*, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.fk
                                     ORDER BY s.pk) rnk
          FROM YOUR_TABLE s) x
 WHERE x.rnk = 1
```

...or using CTE (no performance difference):

```
WITH example AS (
  SELECT s.*, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.fk
                               ORDER BY s.pk) rnk
    FROM sample s)
SELECT x.* 
  FROM example x
 WHERE x.rnk = 1
```

Proof:

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 1 AS PK, 11 AS FK, 'A' AS [TYPE]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS PK, 11 AS FK, 'B' AS [TYPE]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS PK, 12 AS FK, 'B' AS [TYPE]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS PK, 13 AS FK, 'C' AS [TYPE]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS PK, 13 AS FK, 'D' AS [TYPE]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS PK, 14 AS FK, 'D' AS [TYPE])
SELECT x.* 
  FROM (SELECT s.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.fk
                                          ORDER BY s.pk) rnk
          FROM sample s) x
 WHERE x.rnk = 1
```

Result:

```
pk   fk   type
----------------
1    11   A
3    12   B
4    13   C
6    14   D
```

Comment: Works great, now I've got my head around window functions.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, doesn't this completely fail if the data has the `PK`s and `FK`s in mismatched order? For instance if you switch rows `1` and `2` in the data, you are still supposed to return type `A` for that row... but since 1 is the smallest `PK`, this solution returns type `B`...

Comment: In other words, I guess you can just fix it by doing `ORDER BY s.Type` instead of `ORDER BY s.pk`. I think this is important though.

Comment: When I incorporated this into my program I changed the window function to `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY s.fk ORDER BY s.Type)`.  That seemed to fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

So, for each FK value, you want the minimal PK value that matches, and the corresponding type for the PK?  As ever, do it in steps.

Which are the PK values we want?

```
SELECT FK, MIN(PK) AS PK
  FROM SimplifiedData
 GROUP BY FK
```

How to get the corresponding rows - why, join with the main table, of course:

```
SELECT S.PK, S.FK, S.Type
  FROM SimplifiedData AS S
  JOIN (SELECT FK, MIN(PK) AS PK
          FROM SimplifiedData
         GROUP BY FK
       ) AS T ON S.PK = T.PK
 ORDER BY S.FK;
```